# Making ESLint work for files which are loaded by others

Tags: eslint

I have a set of scripts in which one loads another script file and uses the functions defined in it.

For example, let's say I have `main.js` script with the following source

```
load("helper.js");
var stdin = new java.io.BufferedReader( new java.io.InputStreamReader(java.lang.System['in']) );
function readline() {
    var line = stdin.readLine();
    return line;
}
var N = parseInt(readline());
for(var i = 0; i<  N; i++)
{
    print("fd630b881935b5d43180ff301525488a");
    var num = parseInt(readline());
    var ans = perfectNumberCheck(num);
    print(ans);
    print("dc29e6fa38016b00627b6e52956f3c64");
}
```

I have another script file, `helper.js` which has the following source

```
function perfectNumberCheck(num) {
    if(num == 1) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    var halfNum = (num/2) + 1;
    var sum = 0;
    var retVal = 0;
    for(var i=1 ; i < halfNum; i++){
        if(num % i === 0){
            sum = sum + i;  
        }
    }
    if(sum == num){
        retVal = 1;
    }
    else {
        retVal = 0;
    }
    return retVal; 
}
```

As it can be seen, `main.js` uses the function `perfectNumberCheck`. Now, when I run ESLint on both the files using `eslint main.js helper.js` or by using `eslint *.js`, I get the `no-unused-vars` error `'perfectNumberCheck' is defined but never used` even though it is being used in `main.js`.

I want to keep this error in the configuration but don't want ESLint to show it in such cases.

Is there a way to make ESLint resolve these dependencies without writing the entire code in a single script file?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a comment like `/* exported perfectNumberCheck */` to `helper.js` to tell `no-unused-vars` that the function is used elsewhere outside that file:

```
/* exported perfectNumberCheck */
function perfectNumberCheck() {
    // ...
}
```

By itself, ESLint lints each file in isolation, so it will not resolve identifiers defined in other files. The [`/* exported ... */` comment](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#exported) and [globals](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) allow you to inform ESLint of dependencies in other files.

Since exported comments are intended to be used to indicate names that are used elsewhere by being present in the global scope, they have no effect when the file's source in not in the global scope. Specifically, quoting the docs:

> Note that `/* exported */` has no effect for any of the following:
>
> - when the environment is `node` or `commonjs`
> - when `parserOptions.sourceType` is `module`
> - when `ecmaFeatures.globalReturn` is `true`

Comment: With `/* exported perfectNumberCheck */` in `helper.js`, running `eslint helper.js`, you still got `'perfectNumberCheck' is defined but never used`? Can you share a code block that will reproduce that in the [online demo](http://eslint.org/demo/)?

Comment: You can use the code block for `helper.js` in the question. On the demo website, under _Rules Configuration_, please choose _node_. With the comment `/* exported perfectNumberCheck */` on the first line, you will get the error **2:10 - 'perfectNumberCheck' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)**

Comment: Aha! I copied over a note from the docs and added it to my answer. Since Node.js adds a its module wrapper around files when they're loaded, variables are not globally scoped, so exported comments have no effect. Why are you using the `node` environment but not `require()`? Are you not executing in `node`?

Comment: Actually, no. The programs are executed using Rhino and/or Spidermonkey. I couldn't figure out which environment out of the given ones should be used. Could you suggest one?

Comment: ESLint doesn't currently have a `rhino` environment option, though [sindresorhus/globals](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globals), from which we pull environment global variables, already [has them defined](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globals/blob/d254dcaff737bd4873cf36ba9ce25a1eb0c4b372/globals.json#L974). Nobody's asked for `rhino` yet, but there's [willingness to add it if we get a request](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/2442#issuecomment-99598272), so please go ahead and [file an issue](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/contributing/changes) to request it!

Comment: /* exported x */ works for variables but not for functions.